# PHP - validation message appears even though I have filled in the required fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am seeing a strange issue on my test website. The website can be viewed here and it's a test site so there's no payment (an no payment details entry is required).

https://puffpastrydelights.com/order-online/

So what I am trying to do is ensure the user has provided a delivery date or time if they choose delivery, or ensure they have provided a pickup date and time if they choose pickup.

So for replication, if you order a food item, in the shopping cart select pickup and then in the checkout page fill all the details, your checkout will process and everything is fine.

Now try the same again but this time select delivery in the cart page before you head to checkout, you will see it will show a validation error stating to provide delivery date and time even though you have. It's this I am unsure on and can't see in my code what's causing this issue:

```
// Hide Local Pickup shipping method
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'hide_local_pickup_method');
function hide_local_pickup_method( $fields_pickup) {    
    // change below for the method
    $shipping_method_pickup ='local_pickup:2';
    // change below for the list of fields. Add (or delete) the field name you want (or don’t want) to use
    $hide_fields_pickup = array( 'billing_company', 'billing_state', 'billing_company');
    $shipping_fields_pickup = array( 'shipping_first_name', 'shipping_last_name', 'shipping_company', 'shipping_address_1', 'shipping_address_2', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_postcode');
     $hide_pickup_date_time = array( 'pickup_date', 'pickup_time');
     $hide_delivery_date_time = array( 'delivery_date', 'delivery_time');
    
    $chosen_methods_pickup = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_pickup = $chosen_methods_pickup[0];
 
    foreach($hide_fields_pickup as $field_pickup ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup) {
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['required'] = false;
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'hide_pickup';
        }
        $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'billing-dynamic_pickup';
    }
    
        foreach($shipping_fields_pickup as $shipping_field ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup) {
            $fields_pickup['shipping'][$shipping_field]['required'] = false;
        }
    }
        
    foreach($hide_pickup_date_time as $pickup_date_time ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup != $shipping_method_pickup) {
            $fields_pickup['order'][$pickup_date_time]['required'] = false;
        }
    }
    
    foreach($hide_delivery_date_time as $delivery_date_time ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup != $shipping_method_pickup) {
            $fields_pickup['order'][$delivery_date_time]['required'] = false;
        }       
    }
    
    return $fields_pickup;
}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
     $shipping_method_pickup ='local_pickup:2';
     $chosen_methods_pickup = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
     $chosen_shipping_pickup = $chosen_methods_pickup[0];
    
    
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
   if ($chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup) {
    if ( ! $_POST['pickup_date'] ){
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please provide a Pickup Date.' ), 'error' );
     }
    
    if ( ! $_POST['pickup_time'] ){
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please provide a Pickup Time.' ), 'error' );
     }
     } else {
         if ( ! $_POST['delivery_date'] ){
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please provide a Delivery Date.' ), 'error' );
     }
    
    if ( ! $_POST['delivery_time'] ){
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please provide a Delivery Time.' ), 'error' );
     }
     }
}
```

These fields are custom fields and are set below like so:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field($checkout)
{
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field"><h3>' . __('Pickup/Delivery') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field(
        'delivery_date',
        array(

            'type' => 'date',
            'required' => 'true',
            'class' => array(

                'delivery-date-class form-row-wide'

            ),
            'label' => __('Delivery Date'),
        ),
        $checkout->get_value('delivery_date')
    );

    woocommerce_form_field(
        'delivery_time',
        array(

            'type' => 'time',
            'required' => 'true',
            'class' => array(

                'delivery-time-class form-row-wide'

            ),
            'label' => __('Delivery Time'),
        ),
        $checkout->get_value('delivery_time')
    );

    woocommerce_form_field(
        'pickup_date',
        array(

            'type' => 'date',
            'required' => 'true',
            'class' => array(

                'pickup-date-class form-row-wide'

            ),
            'label' => __('Pickup Date'),
        ),
        $checkout->get_value('pickup_date')
    );

    woocommerce_form_field(
        'pickup_time',
        array(

            'type' => 'time',
            'required' => 'true',
            'class' => array(

                'pickup-time-class form-row-wide'

            ),
            'label' => __('Pickup Time'),
        ),
        $checkout->get_value('pickup_time')
    );
    
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I have tried to select both shipping methods in the cart but I am not seeing any errors.

Comment: if(! $_POST) does not look valid to me unless I am missing something shouldn't that be where you check $POST is not set or not empty??

Comment: @Vincenzo , that’s weird. What happens if you tried to switch’s hopping during checkout page, do you get it then?

Comment: @kevin - yeah it looked strange to me. I was following the explanation to set it in this link by woocommerce - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#

Comment: I saw it in the docs that's weird I think it might be a typo...Did you try removing it and use the ordinary way of checking...It appears nothing is wrong with your code except that part

Comment: I just tested that with a simple form and that ! $POST does not work it is invalid...it just returns blank even if $POST isset...

Comment: @KevinGales Interesting... let me change it to is empty and see what happens... give me couple of moments

Comment: Hmmm.. didn't work when I changed to empty:  `if ( empty($_POST['delivery_date'] )){
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please provide a Delivery Date.' ), 'error' );
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is correct, no errors.**

The problem is that you have two HTML elements with the same id (and name) on the checkout page.

The fields are:

- `delivery_date` there is a **date** input field and a **text** input field with this id (and name)
- `delivery_time` there is a **time** input field and a **text** input field with this id (and name)
- `pickup_date` there is a **date** input field and a **text** input field with this id (and name)
- `pickup_time` there is a **time** input field and a **text** input field with this id (and name)

As you can see from this screenshot *(the text input fields are hidden)*:

[image]

**Try removing the text input fields** or, if needed, **change the id attribute value to be unique on the page**.

In the code you published there is no reference to the text input fields, most likely they are in your `functions.php`.

Comment: Wow, what a coincidence on the naming. Just been testing last 5 mins on various combinations and looks like it's working. Thanks man. I changed the id in the function where I have created the fields and in the code where I check the $POST requests. I also made it check to see if empty